# Is upvoting like rating?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, up-votes

Since the SO site provides the total number if upvotes and downvotes, it is somehow like a total rating for the answer.
From time to time I face some questions with several answers(I don't want to point to specific ones).
The point is that an answer might be better than the other but still both are good, and both answer the question in their own way.

I see that an answer needs upvoting more than the other. Of course I can't do that, the only way is to upvote the best one and leave the other with no upvotes.
But still I don't see that the other answer shouldn't be left. Some users needs to be encouraged for their good work.
So what I'm encouraged/discouraged to do in this case? Should I upvote both answers or the best one?

Comment: If you think both answers are useful then you can definitely upvote both - that's fine :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voting is totally up to yourself.  There are no rules how you should vote.*

Do as you like (except for voting abuse).

<sub>* Imagine someone would tell you how to vote in an election. Would not make much sense.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Voting isn't like a rating, it **is** a rating.  It is a rough measure of what the community thinks about the quality of a specific post.  It isn't perfect, but it does help separate the quality posts from the crowd.  There's no restriction on the number of answers on a specific question you can vote for.  If a post has multiple good answers, then by all means vote for all of them.

There are intentionally very few restrictions on voting.  In fact the only things you can't do is vote for yourself or commit voting fraud by creating fake accounts to vote for yourself (or your friends), or by intentionally targeting a specific user votes.